# ActiveRecord double belongs_to doesn't include the foreign relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

In Rails 3.2, I have a dictionary with words and references, named "gotowords" which store the word they belong to in `word_id` and the word they make reference to in `reference_id` (ie. `gotofrom` in the models):

```
create_table "words", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "word"
  t.text     "definition"
end

create_table "gotowords", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "word_id"
  t.integer "reference_id"
end
```

With the models:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gotowords
  has_many :gotofroms, class_name: "Gotoword", foreign_key: "reference_id"
end

class Gotoword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
  belongs_to :gotofrom, class_name: "Word", foreign_key: "id"
end
```

The following query works, but makes another query for each `gotofroms.word` which is apparently not included:

```
@words = Word.includes(:gotowords, :gotofroms)
```

I cannot (for now) refactor like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040613/activerecord-double-belongs-to) suggests, as the application is pretty huge and it would have too many consequences. That said, I can live with the supplemental query, but it bugs me... Adding `inverse_of` as is doesn't solve the problem:

```
has_many :gotowords, inverse_of: :word
has_many :gotofroms, class_name: "Gotoword", foreign_key: "reference_id", inverse_of: :gotofrom
```

Is there a solution to include `Word` twice in that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preload`. It works a bit different, but might still help to eliminate duplicated db queries:

```
@words = Word.preload(:gotowords, :gotofroms)
```

Comment: Thanks, looked promising, but I still have the duplicate queries.

Comment: Thanks to you I discovered `eager_load` which is a bit better for performance but doesn't solve the duplicate queries either.

Comment: Strange that is does not help. Can you post the db queries from your log?

Comment: The DB queries for `preload` (or `includes`) followed by the ones for `eager_load` in case: [http://pastebin.com/0TtpRBKV](http://pastebin.com/0TtpRBKV)

Comment: That's really strange. Maybe it's more related to some code in the view then?

Comment: There's actually no code in the view, it generates some JSON with [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. As you see, additional queries are for the `words` table, and not for the `gotowords`. Can you try adding `inverse_of: :gotowords` and `inverse_of: :gotofroms` to relationships in the `Gotoword` model?

Comment: I removed the RABL/JSON part, did some simple loop in the view, then added both `inverse_of:` in `Word` and `Gotoword` models, I still have the duplicate queries with `preload` or the others... I think I will have to live with it :)

Comment: looks like it :) strange that the ids for separate queries differ from the preload query too.